# Logout Only Works After Go Restart

Tags: go, session-cookies, middleware, gorilla

Problem Details and Results

I really really do not understand what is wrong here and how to fix it. So, my goals are:

1. All projects are showing when there are no user logged in, BUT, the edit and delete button is hidden. This works fine
2. When a user/author login, their project data will be shown according to their own project data. So if user A has project AB, AC, and AD, user C has only CA, user B has BA and BB, they will be shown exactly like that. This works fine too
3. When logout is clicked, back to goal number 1. THIS IS FOR SOME REASON NOT WORKING. It has worked before but because I have made many changes without reviewing per changes, I am really confused where this issue lies. So, when we click on logout, instead of doing goal number 1, it's not only not doing goal number 1 but also violating goal number 2. After the logout button is clicked, all cards from every user shows along with the edit and delete button. I tried to google and chatgpt things and one attempt leads to another problem so I'm reverting back all the changes to this problem instead.

Go code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "text/template"
    "time"
    connection "upgrade/Connection"
    middleware "upgrade/Middleware"

    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v5"
    "github.com/labstack/echo-contrib/session"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

type Project struct {
    ID     int
    Author string

    Project_Title string

    Start_Date  time.Time
    Finish_Date time.Time
    Duration    time.Duration

    Description string

    Toggle_A bool
    Toggle_B bool
    Toggle_C bool
    Toggle_D bool

    Image string

    Format_Start_Date  string
    Format_Finish_Date string
    Formatted_Duration string
}

type User struct {
    ID         int
    First_Name string
    Last_Name  string
    Email      string
    Password   string
}

type Data_Session struct {
    Login_State bool
    First_Name  string
}

var User_Session = Data_Session{}

func main() {
    connection.Database_Connect()

    e := echo.New()

    e.Use(session.Middleware(sessions.NewCookieStore([]byte("session"))))

    e.Static("/Public", "Public")
    e.Static("/Uploads", "Uploads")

    e.GET("/", Main_Page)
    e.GET("/Project-Detail/:id", Project_Detail)
    e.GET("/Edit-Project/:id", Edit_Project)

    e.GET("/Login", Logging_in)
    e.GET("/Register", Registration)

    e.POST("/", middleware.Upload_Image(Project_Form_Value))
    e.POST("/Delete-Project/:id", Delete_Project)
    e.POST("/Edit-Project/:id", middleware.Upload_Image(Save_Changes))

    e.POST("/Login", Login)
    e.POST("/Register", Register)

    e.POST("/Logout", Logout)

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start("localhost:5000"))
}

func Main_Page(c echo.Context) error {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c)

    // Check if any user is logged in
    if sess.Values["Login_State"] == true {
        User_Session.Login_State = sess.Values["Login_State"].(bool)
        User_Session.First_Name = sess.Values["First_Name"].(string)
        AuthorID := sess.Values["ID"].(int)

        data, _ := connection.Conn.Query(context.Background(), "SELECT tb_project.id, project_title, start_date, finish_date, description, toggle_a, toggle_b, toggle_c, toggle_d, image, tb_user.first_name as author FROM tb_project JOIN tb_user ON tb_project.author_id = tb_user.id WHERE tb_project.author_id = $1 ORDER BY tb_project.id", AuthorID)

        var result []Project

        for data.Next() {
            var each = Project{}
            err := data.Scan(&each.ID, &each.Project_Title, &each.Start_Date, &each.Finish_Date, &each.Description, &each.Toggle_A, &each.Toggle_B, &each.Toggle_C, &each.Toggle_D, &each.Image, &each.Author)

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
                return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
            }

            each.Duration = each.Finish_Date.Sub(each.Start_Date)
            each.Formatted_Duration = Duration_Formatting(each.Duration)

            result = append(result, each)
        }

        Data := map[string]interface{}{
            "Projects":      result,
            "Flash_Status":  sess.Values["Status"],
            "Flash_Message": sess.Values["Message"],
            "Data_Session":  User_Session,
        }

        delete(sess.Values, "Message")
        delete(sess.Values, "Status")
        sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())

        var tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles("Views/Index.html")

        if err != nil {
            return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
        }

        Map_Duration_Formatting := template.FuncMap{
            "Duration_Formatting": Duration_Formatting,
        }

        tmpl = tmpl.Funcs(Map_Duration_Formatting)

        return tmpl.Execute(c.Response(), Data)
    } else {
        // No user is logged in, fetch all projects
        data, _ := connection.Conn.Query(context.Background(), "SELECT tb_project.id, project_title, start_date, finish_date, description, toggle_a, toggle_b, toggle_c, toggle_d, image, tb_user.first_name as author FROM tb_project JOIN tb_user ON tb_project.author_id = tb_user.id ORDER BY tb_project.id")

        var result []Project

        for data.Next() {
            var each = Project{}
            err := data.Scan(&each.ID, &each.Project_Title, &each.Start_Date, &each.Finish_Date, &each.Description, &each.Toggle_A, &each.Toggle_B, &each.Toggle_C, &each.Toggle_D, &each.Image, &each.Author)

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err.Error())
                return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
            }

            each.Duration = each.Finish_Date.Sub(each.Start_Date)
            each.Formatted_Duration = Duration_Formatting(each.Duration)

            result = append(result, each)
        }

        Data := map[string]interface{}{
            "Projects":      result,
            "Flash_Status":  sess.Values["Status"],
            "Flash_Message": sess.Values["Message"],
            "Data_Session":  User_Session,
        }

        delete(sess.Values, "Message")
        delete(sess.Values, "Status")
        sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())

        var tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles("Views/Index.html")

        if err != nil {
            return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
        }

        Map_Duration_Formatting := template.FuncMap{
            "Duration_Formatting": Duration_Formatting,
        }

        tmpl = tmpl.Funcs(Map_Duration_Formatting)

        return tmpl.Execute(c.Response(), Data)
    }
}

func Project_Detail(c echo.Context) error {
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.Param("id"))

    var Project_Detail = Project{}

    err := connection.Conn.QueryRow(context.Background(), "SELECT tb_project.id, project_title, start_date, finish_date, description, toggle_a, toggle_b, toggle_c, toggle_d, image, tb_user.first_name as author FROM tb_project JOIN tb_user ON tb_project.author_id = tb_user.id WHERE tb_project.id=$1", id).Scan(&Project_Detail.ID, &Project_Detail.Project_Title, &Project_Detail.Start_Date, &Project_Detail.Finish_Date, &Project_Detail.Description, &Project_Detail.Toggle_A, &Project_Detail.Toggle_B, &Project_Detail.Toggle_C, &Project_Detail.Toggle_D, &Project_Detail.Image, &Project_Detail.Author)

    if err != nil {
        if err == pgx.ErrNoRows {
            return c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, map[string]string{"message": "Project not found"})
        }
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"mesage": err.Error()})
    }

    Project_Detail.Format_Start_Date = Project_Detail.Start_Date.Format("Jan 2, 2006")
    Project_Detail.Format_Finish_Date = Project_Detail.Finish_Date.Format("Jan 2, 2006")

    Project_Detail.Duration = Project_Detail.Finish_Date.Sub(Project_Detail.Start_Date)
    Project_Detail.Formatted_Duration = Duration_Formatting(Project_Detail.Duration)

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "Project_Detail": Project_Detail,
    }

    tmpl, err_too := template.ParseFiles("Views/Project-Detail.html")

    if err_too != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"mesage": err_too.Error()})
    }

    return tmpl.Execute(c.Response(), data)
}

func Duration_Formatting(Duration time.Duration) string {
    if Duration <= 24*time.Hour {
        return "Less than a day"
    }

    Days := int(Duration.Hours() / 24)
    Weeks := Days / 7
    Months := Days / 30
    Years := Months / 12

    if Years > 1 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%d years", Years)
    } else if Years == 1 {
        return "A year"
    } else if Months > 1 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%d months", Months)
    } else if Months == 1 {
        return "A month"
    } else if Weeks > 1 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%d weeks", Weeks)
    } else if Weeks == 1 {
        return "A week"
    } else if Days > 1 {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%d days", Days)
    } else {
        return "A day"
    }
}

// POST
func Project_Form_Value(c echo.Context) error {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c)
    Author := sess.Values["ID"].(int)

    Project_Title := c.FormValue("Project_Title")
    Start_Date := c.FormValue("Start_Date")
    Finish_Date := c.FormValue("Finish_Date")
    Description := c.FormValue("Description")

    Toggle_A := c.FormValue("Toggle_A") == "on"
    Toggle_B := c.FormValue("Toggle_B") == "on"
    Toggle_C := c.FormValue("Toggle_C") == "on"
    Toggle_D := c.FormValue("Toggle_D") == "on"

    Image := c.Get("File_Data").(string)

    _, err := connection.Conn.Exec(context.Background(), "INSERT INTO tb_project (project_title, start_date, finish_date, description, toggle_a, toggle_b, toggle_c, toggle_d, image, author_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)", Project_Title, Start_Date, Finish_Date, Description, Toggle_A, Toggle_B, Toggle_C, Toggle_D, Image, Author)

    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
    }

    fmt.Println(Project_Title, Start_Date, Finish_Date, Description, Toggle_A, Toggle_B, Toggle_C, Toggle_D)

    return c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/")
}

func Delete_Project(c echo.Context) error {
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.Param("id"))

    _, err := connection.Conn.Exec(context.Background(), "DELETE FROM tb_project WHERE id=$1", id)

    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
    }

    return c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/")
}

func Edit_Project(c echo.Context) error {
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.Param("id"))

    var Previous_Data = Project{}

    err := connection.Conn.QueryRow(context.Background(), "SELECT id, project_title, start_date, finish_date, description, toggle_a, toggle_b, toggle_c, toggle_d, image FROM tb_project WHERE id=$1", id).Scan(&Previous_Data.ID, &Previous_Data.Project_Title, &Previous_Data.Start_Date, &Previous_Data.Finish_Date, &Previous_Data.Description, &Previous_Data.Toggle_A, &Previous_Data.Toggle_B, &Previous_Data.Toggle_C, &Previous_Data.Toggle_D, &Previous_Data.Image)

    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
    }

    SD_F := Previous_Data.Start_Date.Format("2006-01-02")
    FD_F := Previous_Data.Finish_Date.Format("2006-01-02")

    data := map[string]interface{}{
        "Previous_Data": Previous_Data,
        "SD_F":          SD_F,
        "FD_F":          FD_F,
        "PDID":          Previous_Data.ID,
    }

    tmpl, err_too := template.ParseFiles("Views/Edit-Project-Form.html")

    if err_too != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
    }

    return tmpl.Execute(c.Response(), data)
}

func Save_Changes(c echo.Context) error {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c)
    Author := sess.Values["ID"].(int)

    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(c.Param("id"))

    Project_Title := c.FormValue("Project_Title")
    Start_Date := c.FormValue("Start_Date")
    Finish_Date := c.FormValue("Finish_Date")
    Description := c.FormValue("Description")

    Toggle_A := c.FormValue("Toggle_A") == "on"
    Toggle_B := c.FormValue("Toggle_B") == "on"
    Toggle_C := c.FormValue("Toggle_C") == "on"
    Toggle_D := c.FormValue("Toggle_D") == "on"

    Image := c.Get("File_Data").(string)

    _, err := connection.Conn.Exec(context.Background(), "UPDATE tb_project SET project_title=$1, start_date=$2, finish_date=$3, description=$4, toggle_a=$5, toggle_b=$6, toggle_c=$7, toggle_d=$8, image=$9, author_id=$10 WHERE id=$11", Project_Title, Start_Date, Finish_Date, Description, Toggle_A, Toggle_B, Toggle_C, Toggle_D, Image, Author, id)

    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
    }

    redirectURL := fmt.Sprintf("/?id=%d#ppc-container", id)
    return c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, redirectURL)
}

// GET
func Registration(c echo.Context) error {
    var tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles("Views/Registration-Form.html")

    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
    }

    return tmpl.Execute(c.Response(), nil)
}

// POST
func Register(c echo.Context) error {
    err := c.Request().ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    First_Name := c.FormValue("First_Name")
    Last_Name := c.FormValue("Last_Name")
    Email := c.FormValue("Email")
    Password := c.FormValue("Password")

    passwordHash, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(Password), 10)

    _, err = connection.Conn.Exec(context.Background(), "INSERT INTO tb_user(first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)", First_Name, Last_Name, Email, passwordHash)
    if err != nil {
        redirectWithMessage(c, "Registration failed. Please try again", false, "/Register")
    }

    return redirectWithMessage(c, "Registration complete. Please login", true, "/Login")
}

// GET
func Logging_in(c echo.Context) error {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c)

    Flash := map[string]interface{}{
        "Flash_Status":  sess.Values["Status"],
        "Flash_Message": sess.Values["Message"],
    }

    delete(sess.Values, "Message")
    delete(sess.Values, "Status")
    sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())

    var tmpl, err = template.ParseFiles("Views/Login-Form.html")

    if err != nil {
        return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, map[string]string{"message": err.Error()})
    }

    return tmpl.Execute(c.Response(), Flash)
}

// POST
func Login(c echo.Context) error {
    err := c.Request().ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    Email := c.FormValue("Email")
    Password := c.FormValue("Password")

    User := User{}
    err = connection.Conn.QueryRow(context.Background(), "SELECT id, first_name, email, password FROM tb_user WHERE email = $1", Email).Scan(&User.ID, &User.First_Name, &User.Email, &User.Password)
    if err != nil {
        return redirectWithMessage(c, "Unregistered or incorrect email data", false, "/Login")
    }

    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(User.Password), []byte(Password))
    if err != nil {
        return redirectWithMessage(c, "Incorrect Password", false, "/Login")
    }

    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c)
    sess.Options.MaxAge = 21600 //6 hours
    sess.Values["Message"] = "Logged in"
    sess.Values["Status"] = true
    sess.Values["ID"] = User.ID
    sess.Values["First_Name"] = User.First_Name
    sess.Values["Email"] = User.Email
    sess.Values["Login_State"] = true
    sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())

    return c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/")
}

func Logout(c echo.Context) error {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c)
    sess.Options.MaxAge = -1
    sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())

    return c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, "/")
}

func redirectWithMessage(c echo.Context, Message string, Status bool, Path string) error {
    sess, _ := session.Get("session", c)
    sess.Values["Message"] = Message
    sess.Values["Status"] = Status
    sess.Save(c.Request(), c.Response())

    return c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, Path)
}
```

template

```
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center gap-2 mb-4 mb-lg-0">

          {{if not .Data_Session.Login_State}}
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-light px-4 rounded-pill dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false">
              Login
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu rounded-4">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-top-2" href="/Login">Login</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item rounded-bottom-2" href="/Register">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <button type="button" class="btn rounded-pill px-4 btn-outline-secondary" title="Send a Message"
            data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#send-message">
            Contact <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope fa-fw ms-1 hover-exception"></i>
          </button>
          {{else}}

          <p class="my-auto">Hi there, {{.Data_Session.First_Name}}!</p>
          <p class="my-auto fs-5">|</p>
          <form action="/Logout" method="POST" id="logout"></form>
          <button onclick="document.getElementById('logout').submit()"
            class="btn btn-outline-secondary px-4 rounded-pill">Logout <i
              class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket fa-fw ms-1 hover-exception"></i></button>
          {{end}}

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  {{if .Flash_Message}}
  {{if .Flash_Status}}
  <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center position-fixed" style="z-index: 10000;">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show rounded-pill w-50 mt-3" role="alert">
      <strong>{{.Flash_Message}}</strong>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{else}}
  <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center position-fixed" style="z-index: 10000;">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show rounded-pill w-50 mt-3" role="alert">
      <strong>{{.Flash_Message}}</strong>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{end}}
  {{end}}

  <div class="scrollspy" data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-target" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true">

    <!-- Project Preview Cards -->
    <div class="bg-body container-fluid p-5 rounded-top-5 shadow-sm">

      <div id="scroll-2">

        <div class="d-flex gap-3 justify-content-between align-items-center mx-3">
          <h3 class="mb-0">Projects</h3>

          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          {{if .Data_Session.Login_State}}
          <button type="button" class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-secondary btn-sm px-3" title="New Project"
            data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#add-new">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus fa-sm me-1 hover-exception"></i>
            Add
          </button>
          {{end}}

        </div>

        <div class="container" id="ppc-container">
          {{range $index, $data := .Projects}}
          <div class="card rounded-4 border-0 shadow-sm ppc" style="width: 16em;">
            <img src="/Uploads/{{$data.Image}}" class="card-img-top rounded-top-4" alt="Mobile App"
              style="height: 10.25em; object-fit: cover;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <a href="Project-Detail/{{$data.ID}}" class="card-title ppc-title" style="text-decoration: none;">
                <h6 class="text-truncate">{{$data.Project_Title}}</h6>
              </a>
              <p class="text-muted" style="font-size: small; line-height: .5;">Duration: {{$data.Formatted_Duration}}
              </p>
              <p class="card-text lh-sm"
                style="font-size: small; display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-line-clamp: 3; overflow: hidden;">
                {{$data.Description}}</p>
              <div class="d-flex gap-2 my-4">
                {{if $data.Toggle_A}}
                <i class="fa-brands fa-square-js fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
                {{end}}
                {{if $data.Toggle_B}}
                <i class="fa-brands fa-bootstrap fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
                {{end}}
                {{if $data.Toggle_C}}
                <i class="fa-brands fa-golang fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
                {{end}}
                {{if $data.Toggle_D}}
                <i class="fa-brands fa-react fa-lg fa-fw"></i>
                {{end}}
              </div>

              {{if $.Data_Session.Login_State}}
              <div class="d-flex flex-row gap-2">
                <form class="container-fluid g-0" action="/Edit-Project/{{$data.ID}}" method="GET">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-secondary btn-sm w-100"
                    data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit-project">
                    Edit
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square fa-fw ms-1 hover-exception"></i>
                  </button>
                </form>

                <form class="container-fluid g-0" action="/Delete-Project/{{$data.ID}}" method="POST">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn rounded-pill btn-outline-danger btn-sm w-100"
                    data-index="{{$index}}">
                    Delete <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can fa-fw ms-1 hover-exception"></i>
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
              {{end}}
              
            </div>
          </div>
          {{end}}

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: `c.Redirect(http.StatusMovedPermanently, ...)` will make the browser cache the redirect, so if you hit /Logout more than once, the browser will not make the request and navigate to / immediately. Use http.StatusFound instead.

Comment: i tried to change that in my logout func and the same problem still occurs, i tried changing that in every func and the problem still occurs too :') (and i also cleared the browser cache, and restarted go each time, of course)

Comment: the conditional template for the navbar has not been implemented in all other html files but does that matter? because the problem is on the index, right? and also because of the data that shows from different users too and the edit and the delete buttons too. it's not logging out. I tried manually deleting the cookie but after refresh the cookie is there again. like so, I have to always restart go :')

Comment: nevermind, turns out this is all because i havent added 
User_Session.Login_State = sess.Values["Login_State"] == false
User_Session.First_Name = ""

inside else inside main page func. but thank you so much for responding to me, Jim! I appreciate you ^_^